# In Maven, including dependency via <dependency> OR importing the package inside <Import-Package>. Which one of the two should be used?

Tags: maven

1. In my project core pom.xml, there is Import-Package javax.inject;version=0.0.0  and also following maven dependency. I am not clear why both are being used? I mean, if we are already including the dependency via below-mentioned method, then why do we need to use the same inside Import-Package?

   ```
           <configuration>
               <instructions>                     
                   <Import-Package>
                     javax.inject;version=0.0.0,                            
                     org.xbc.web.core.service;version=0.0.0,
                       *
                   </Import-Package>
                   <Sling-Model-Packages>
                       org.xbc.core
                   </Sling-Model-Packages>
               </instructions>
           </configuration>
   ```

Above mentioned packages are duplicated in below dependencies

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.xbc.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>fullton-project.core</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

2. The same scenario is happening in my project. My project A is dependent on project B, there also I have noticed that package path has been added in Import-Package and dependency has been added for project B in core/pom.xml of Project A. why both? Somebody, please clarify this.

Comment: Is this OSGI? Then you may need Import-Package additionally to the dependency.

Comment: Yes, OSGI? But what sort of packages which cannot be resolved by dependency tag?